# Angular UI Router injector Error in my framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular framework I am building that I am trying to make router agnostic, I would like to be able to use any router. So far I have tested it with ng router and it works fine, but when I try to use UI-Router I am getting the injector error. I am not sure if I have placed it in the wrong module, or if it a deeper issue. The framework broadcasts a route or a state, depending on how I set up the Framework directive. I have injected UI-Router into my main module and injected $stateProvider into my controller that needs to use it. I am stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is main module:

```
 (function () {
"use strict";

   angular.module("app", ["ptFramework", "ui.router", "ngStorage",    "ui.bootstrap"]);
})();
```

Here is framework module:

```
 (function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("ptFramework", [,"ptMenu", "ptDashboard"]);
```

})();

Here is framework controller:

```
 (function () {
"use strict";

angular.module("ptFramework").controller("ptFrameworkController",
['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$stateProvider',
    function ($scope, $window, $timeout, $rootScope, $stateProvider) {

        $scope.isMenuVisible = true;
        $scope.isMenuButtonVisible = true;
        $scope.isMenuVertical = true;

        $scope.$on('pt-menu-item-selected-event', function (evt, data) {
            $scope.stateString = data.state;
            $stateProvider.go(data.state);
            checkWidth();
            broadcastMenuState();
        });

        $scope.$on('pt-menu-orientation-changed-event', function (evt, data) {
            $scope.isMenuVertical = data.isMenuVertical;
            $timeout(function () {
                $($window).trigger('resize');
            }, 0);
        });

        $($window).on('resize.ptFramework', function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                checkWidth();
                broadcastMenuState();
            });
        });
        $scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
            $($window).off("resize.ptFramework"); // remove the handler added earlier
        });

        var checkWidth = function () {
            var width = Math.max($($window).width(), $window.innerWidth);
            $scope.isMenuVisible = (width >= 768);
            $scope.isMenuButtonVisible = !$scope.isMenuVisible;
        };

        $scope.menuButtonClicked = function () {
            $scope.isMenuVisible = !$scope.isMenuVisible;
            broadcastMenuState();

        };

        var broadcastMenuState = function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('pt-menu-show',
                {
                    show: $scope.isMenuVisible,
                    isVertical: $scope.isMenuVertical,
                    allowHorizontalToggle: !$scope.isMenuButtonVisible
                });
        };

        $timeout(function () {
            checkWidth();
        }, 0);

    }
]);
```

})();

As you can see I have injected $stateProvider in both the minsafe array and the function. I dont understand why I am getting this error

Here is the rote.config where I use it:

```
     "use strict";
angular.module('app').config([
    '$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard',
            {
                url: "/dashboard",
                template: "<h1>dashboard</h1>"
            });
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller:

```
$stateProvider.go(data.state);
```

should be

```
$state.go(data.state);
```

As a consequence, inject `$state` instead of `$stateProvider`.

Comment: Thanks, I always though you had to do $stateProvider.state.go. And I obviously had my syntax wrong. Thanks for the help.